# Convert if else statement to a Switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I was responding to a challenge to write C# code taking a if else statement and converting it to a Select statement with all the same outcome. Here is the if else code;

```
// SKU = Stock Keeping Unit. 
// SKU value format: <product #>-<2-letter color code>-<size code>
string sku = "01-MN-L";

string[] product = sku.Split('-');

string type = "";
string color = "";
string size = "";

if (product[0] == "01")
{
    type = "Sweat shirt";
} else if (product[0] == "02")
{
    type = "T-Shirt";
} else if (product[0] == "03")
{
    type = "Sweat pants";
}
else
{
    type = "Other";
}

if (product[1] == "BL")
{
    color = "Black";
} else if (product[1] == "MN")
{
    color = "Maroon";
} else
{
    color = "White";
}

if (product[2] == "S")
{
    size = "Small";
} else if (product[2] == "M")
{
    size = "Medium";
} else if (product[2] == "L")
{
    size = "Large";
} else
{
    size = "One Size Fits All";
}

Console.WriteLine($"Product: {size} {color} {type}");
```

This is my attempt at the problem and if works with the exception, that I can't handle the else
part of the code which would require more than one default: statement in the Switch statement.

```
using System.Drawing;
string color = "";
string type = "";
string size = "";
string sku = "02-BK-R";

string[] product = sku.Split('-');
int skuPart = product.Length;

foreach (string productPart in product)
{
    switch (productPart)
    {
        case "01":
            type = "Sweat Shirt";
            break;
        case "02":
            type = "T-Shirt ";
            break;
        case "03":
            type = "Sweat Pants";
            break;       
        case "MN":
            color = "Maroon";
            break;
        case "BK":
            color = "Black";
            break;

        case "S":
            size = "Small";
            break;
        case "M":
            size = "Medium";
            break;
        case "L":
            size = "Large";
            break;
        default:           
            break;
    }
}

 Console.WriteLine($"Product: {size} {color} {type}");
```

Comment: Your different product codes have different actual meanings. It's not a good idea to combine these into one switch statement. You would be better off maintaining a set of dictionaries for: 1) types; 2) colors; 3) sizes. You can then perform a lookup in all these dictionaries. You could store the default value keyed by an empty string, and if the product is not found, then just lookup empty string to get the default. If you really insist on using a switch, then use three separate switches. Even better, put each one in a function: _e.g._ `string GetProductType(string) ...`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution is to write 3 switch statement for set values of type, color and size. this is how you can write your code:

```
var sku = "01-MN-L";

var product = sku.Split('-');

var type = product[0] switch
{
    "01" => "Sweat shirt",
    "02" => "T-Shirt",
    "03" => "Sweat pants",
    _ => "Other"
};

var color = product[1] switch
{
    "BL" => "Black",
    "MN" => "Maroon",
    _ => "White"
};

var size = product[2] switch
{
    "S" => "Small",
    "M" => "Medium",
    "L" => "Large",
    _ => "One Size Fits All"
};

Console.WriteLine($"Product: {size} {color} {type}");
```

I hope this solution can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your solution was the one listed as an answer. I am just curious if it could be done in one Select statement. I am just learning C# and I spent alot of time trying to make my idea work out, but I'm resolved the your solution is the best approach.

Comment: Overall, it can be done with some tricks but the code turn to something complicated and you should keep it simple. In this way your code is readable and understandable.
Remember to confirm my answer if it's working for you using check sign beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sku = "01-MN-L";

string[] product = sku.Split('-');

string type = "";
string color = "";
string size = "";

switch (product[0])
{
    case "01":
        type = "Sweat shirt";
        break;
    case "02":
        type = "T-Shirt";
        break;
    case "03":
        type = "Sweat pants";
        break;
    default:
        type = "Other";
}

switch (product[1])
{
    case "BL":
        color = "Black";
        break;
    case "MN":
        color = "Maroon";
        break;
    default:
        color = "White";
}

switch (product[2])
{
    case "S":
        size = "Small";
        break;
    case "M":
        size = "Medium";
        break;
    case "L":
        size = "Large";
        break;
    default:
        size = "One Size Fits All";
}

Console.WriteLine($"Product: {size} {color} {type}");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your solution was the one listed as an answer to the challenge. I am just curious if it could be done in one Select statement. I am just learning C# and I spent a lot of time trying to make my idea work out, but I'm resolved that your solution is the best approach.

Comment: @BehzadDara I know you have answer it but in my answer I tried to use a syntax he is familiar with, it could be better for him to understand the solution well.

Comment: @Johnml No, it can't be done in one statement. Even in the if else statement usage it was three statements and that's because you are measuring the values of three different things with several cases each. if you were testing for example just the value of just one variable for more cases you would use one statement. the switch case statement works the same as the if-else statement except that you can't test values like a > b or a < b. the switch statement is more like an if statement with a "==" operator always;